# The limit of a function with sum of two roots.

Tags: limits, functions, roots, limits-without-lhopital

I need to find the limit of the following function:
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}\right).$$
I derived it to the form of:
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{(x^2+2x)^3-(x^3+x^2)^2}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}\right)\left((x^2+2x)^2+(x^2+2x)\sqrt[3]{(x^3+x^2)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x^3+x^2)^4}\right)},$$
hoping that I'd be able to simplify something but still have $\frac{0}{0}$ and don't see how to do that.

Comment: Sorry but are you sure that the sign between two roots is a $+$? In the case it is NOT, you have to multiply and divide the initial expression by the conjugate of the sum $\textit{i.e.}$ $$(\sqrt{x^2+2x}+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2})$$  Otherwise the limit is simply $\infty$. Can you take it from that?

Comment: yes, sadly it's not a -

Comment: Then the limit is $\infty$

Comment: It would be, but x goes to -inifinity, not +infinity.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2+2x}\color{red}{+}\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}\\=\lim_{x\to-\infty}|x|\left(1+{2\over x}\right)^{1\over 2}\color{red}{+}x\left(1+{1\over x}\right)^{1\over3}\\=\lim_{x\to-\infty}|x|\left(1+{1\over 2}\cdot{2\over x}\right)\color{red}{+}x\left(1+{1\over 3}\cdot{1\over x}\right)=-{2\over 3}$$

NB:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1+{1\over n})^p$ can be written as $n(1+{p\over n})$ as the other terms will be like ${1\over n},{1\over n^2}$ etc which can be neglected.($p$ is finite)

Comment: How did you get from your second line to your third? Power series? If so, you should say so.

Comment: The answer should be $-\frac{2}{3}$ (may be wrong) according to the book. And I don't really get what happened between verse 2 and 3.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Are things somewhat clear?

Comment: @R.K. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me change the sign on $x$, I find it easier to think about.
the expression is then

$$\sqrt{x^2-2x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3}$$

Now investigate the two limits 
$$\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x\rightarrow -1$$

and

$$x+\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3}$$ and this latter is equal

to

$$\frac{x^2}{x^2-x\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3}+(\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3})^2}$$

for which I get the limit  of $\frac{1}{3}$ (assuming I haven't made a mistake, (a big assumption)).

Ok so I get the limit $-\frac{2}{3}$ in agreement with the book.

Comment: Why can I just change the signs inside of the roots?

Comment: I just changed the sign of $x$, the limit is now to $+\infty$. Its only a convenience.

Answer (score 0):

For $x<0$,

$$f(x)=-x(1+\frac{2}{x})^{\frac{1}{2}}+x(1+\frac{1}{x})^\frac{1}{3}$$

$$=-x-1+x+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{x}\epsilon(x).$$

the limit is $$-\frac{2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

When $x$ is negative, then $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$, which is positive.  So we have

\begin{align}
& \lim_{x\to-\infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}\right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \lim_{x\to-\infty} \left( -x\sqrt{1 + \frac 2 x} + x \sqrt[3]{1 +  \frac 1 x} \, \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \lim_{x\to-\infty} x\left( -\left( 1 + \frac 2 x \right)^{1/2} + \left( 1 + \frac 1 x \right)^{1/3} \right) \\[10pt]
 = {} & \lim_{x\to-\infty} x\left( -\left( 1 + \frac 2 x \right)^{1/2} + \left( 1 + \frac 1 x \right)^{1/3} \right) \\[10pt]
 = {} & \lim_{u\,\uparrow\, 0} \frac 1 u \left( - (1+2u)^{1/2} + (1+u)^{1/3} \right)  \text{ where } u = \frac 1 x.
\end{align}
L'Hopital's rule can deal with that. (And remember the chain rule when finding $\dfrac d {du} (1+2u)^{1/2}.$)