What is the limit of $\lim_{x \to - \infty} \Big(\sqrt{x^2 +2x} + \sqrt[3]{x^3 + x^2}\Big)$
I've checked the solution and the answer should be $\frac{-2}{3}$. I just do not know at what point I make a mistake and everything evaluates to $\frac{2}{3}$ (so no minus). If you could share your guides, that would be much appreciated, thank you.
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Big(\sqrt{x^2 +2x} + \sqrt[3]{x^3 + x^2}\Big) = \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Big(\sqrt{x^2 + 2x} + \sqrt[3]{- (-x^3 - x^2)}\Big) = 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Big(\sqrt{x^2 + 2x} + \sqrt[3]{-1}\sqrt[3]{(-x^3 - x^2)}\Big) = 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Big(\sqrt{x^2 + 2x} - \sqrt[3]{(-x^3 - x^2)}\Big) = 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Big(\sqrt[6]{(x^2 + 2x)^{3}} - \sqrt[6]{(-x^3 - x^2)^{2}}\Big) 
\end{equation*}
Let $G = \Big(\sqrt[6]{(x^2 + 2x)^{3}} - \sqrt[6]{(-x^3 - x^2)^{2}}\Big)$ and let $S$ be:
\begin{equation*}
    S = \sqrt[6]{(x^2 +2x)^{15}} + \sqrt[6]{(x^2 +2x)^{12}} \cdot \sqrt[6]{(x^3 + x^2)^{2}} + \sqrt[6]{(x^2 + 2x)^{9}} \cdot \sqrt[6]{(x^3 + x^2)^{4}} +
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    + \sqrt[6]{(x^2 +2x)^{6}} \cdot \sqrt[6]{(x^3 + 2x)^{6}} + \sqrt[6]{(x^2 + 2x)^{3}} \cdot \sqrt[6]{(x^3 + x^2)^{8}} + \sqrt[6]{(x^3 + x^2)^{10}}
\end{equation*}
Then:
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Big(\sqrt[6]{(x^2 + 2x)^{3}} - \sqrt[6]{(-x^3 - x^2)^{2}}\Big) = \lim_{x \to - \infty} \frac{G \cdot S}{S} =
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    = \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Bigg(\Big((x^2 + 2x)^{3} - (-x^3 - x^2)^{2}\Big) \cdot \frac{1}{S}\Bigg) =
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    = \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Bigg(\Big((x^2 + 2x)^{3} - (-x^3 - x^2)^{2}\Big)\Bigg) \times % 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \times \Bigg(x^{5}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{15}} + x^{5}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{12}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{2}}  + x^{5}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{9}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{4}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    +  x^{5}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{6}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{6}} + x^{5}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{3}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{8}} + x^{5}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{10}}\Bigg)^{-1} = 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    = \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Bigg(\Big((x^2 + 2x)^{3} - (-x^3 - x^2)^{2}\Big)\Bigg) \times % 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    x^{5}\Bigg(\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{15}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{12}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{2}}  + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{9}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{4}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    +  \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{6}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{6}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{3}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{8}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{10}}\Bigg)^{-1} = 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    = \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Bigg(\Big(4x^5 + 11x^4 + 8x^3\Big)\Bigg) \times % 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    x^{5}\Bigg(\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{15}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{12}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{2}}  + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{9}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{4}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    +  \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{6}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{6}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{3}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{8}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{10}}\Bigg)^{-1} = 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    = \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Bigg(x^{5} \Big(4 + \frac{11}{x} + \frac{8}{x^2}\Big)\Bigg) \times % 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    x^{5}\Bigg(\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{15}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{12}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{2}}  + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{9}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{4}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    +  \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{6}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{6}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{3}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{8}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{10}}\Bigg)^{-1} = 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    = \lim_{x \to - \infty} \Bigg(\Big(4 + \frac{11}{x} + \frac{8}{x^2}\Big)\Bigg) \times % 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \Bigg(\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{15}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{12}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{2}}  + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{9}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{4}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    +  \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{6}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{6}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{2}{x})^{3}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{8}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{10}}\Bigg)^{-1} = 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    = \Bigg(\Big(4 + 0 + 0\Big)\Bigg) \times % 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \Bigg(\sqrt[6]{(1 + 0)^{15}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + 0)^{12}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + 0)^{2}}  + \sqrt[6]{(1 + 0)^{9}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + 0)^{4}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    +  \sqrt[6]{(1 + 0)^{6}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + 0)^{6}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + 0)^{3}}\sqrt[6]{(1 + 0)^{8}} + \sqrt[6]{(1 + 0)^{10}}\Bigg)^{-1} \neq \frac{4}{6} \neq \frac{2}{3}
\end{equation*}

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2053959/42969 for some simpler solutions.

the limit should be $\color{red}-2/3$.

Yes, sorry, I should've indicated that it's a mistake, wanted to provide my calculations

$+1$: Woah, it must've took you like an hour or so to type your whole attempt down! Good efforts!

It took really long crying in pain, but now I see (from the link Martin R has provided) I should've gone for something different ...

Hint:
WLOG $-\dfrac1x=h\implies h\to0^+\implies|h|=+h$  as $\sqrt{h^2}=|h|$
$$x^2+2x=\dfrac{1-2h}{h^2}\implies\sqrt{x^2+2x}=\cdots=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-2h}}h$$
$$\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{-1+h}{h^3}}=-\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1-h}}h$$
Now $\dfrac{\sqrt{1-2h}-\sqrt[3]{1-h}}h=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-2h}-1}h-\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1-h}-1}h$
For the $1$st limit, set $\sqrt{1-2h}-1=u\implies-2h=?$
and $\sqrt[3]{1-h}-1=v$ for the $2$nd

You could calculate your limit in the following way which is simpler than yours:
$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}\right)=$
$=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-x\right)=$
$=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\left[\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x\right)\! \left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x}\;+\\\;+\;\dfrac{\left(\!\sqrt[3]{x^3\!+\!x^2}-x\!\right)\!\!\left(\!\sqrt[3]{\left(x^3\!+\!x^2\right)^2}+x\sqrt[3]{x^3\!+\!x^2}+x^2\!\right)}{\sqrt[3]{\left(x^3\!+\!x^2\right)^2}+x\sqrt[3]{x^3\!+\!x^2}+x^2}\right]\!=$
$\!\!\!\!=\!\!\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\!\!\left[\!\dfrac{\!\sqrt{\!\big(x^2\!+\!2x\big)^{\!2}}\!\!-\!x^2}{|x|\sqrt{1\!+\!\frac2x}\!-\!x}\!+\!\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{\left(x^3\!+\!x^2\right)^3}-x^3}{x^2\!\!\left(\!\sqrt[3]{\left(1\!+\!\frac1x\right)^2}\!+\!\sqrt[3]{1\!+\!\frac1x}\!+\!1\!\right)}\!\right]\!\!=$
$\!\!\!\!=\!\!\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\!\!\left[\!\dfrac{2x}{-x\!\left(\!\sqrt{1\!+\!\frac2x}\!+\!1\!\right)}\!+\!\dfrac{x^2}{x^2\!\!\left(\!\sqrt[3]{\left(1\!+\!\frac1x\right)^2}\!+\!\sqrt[3]{1\!+\!\frac1x}\!+\!1\!\right)}\!\right]\!\!=$
$\!=\!\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\!\left[\dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{1\!+\!\frac2x}+1}+\dfrac1{\sqrt[3]{\left(1\!+\!\frac1x\right)^2}\!+\!\sqrt[3]{1\!+\!\frac1x}\!+\!1}\!\right]\!=$
$=\dfrac{-2}{1+1}+\dfrac1{1+1+1}=$
$=-1+\dfrac13=-\dfrac23\,.$

Faster way is to use the Maclaurin series of $\sqrt{1+x}$ and $\sqrt[3]{1+x}$. But, I don't know how much rigorous this way is accepted.
$$\lim_{x \to - \infty} \sqrt{x^2 +2x} + \sqrt[3]{x^3 + x^2}\\
=\lim_{x \to - \infty} -x\sqrt{1 +\frac2x} + x\sqrt[3]{1 +\frac1x}\\
=\lim_{x \to - \infty} -x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(\tfrac2x)^n+ x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}d_n(\tfrac1x)^n\\
=\lim_{x\to-\infty}-xc_1\frac2x+xd_1\frac1x\\
=d_1-2c_1={\frac13\choose1}-2{\frac13\choose1}=-\frac23
$$
